# Django save an image to database

Tags: python, django

I have a site in Django that upload a photo and than it saves in a folther. After that the program make some processing in the image and save it to database. But it is giving an error:

*UnboundLocalError: local variable 'listing' referenced before assignment*

Part of Model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORIES, default=CATEGORIES[5][1])
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owners")
    bids = models.ManyToManyField(Bid, blank=True, related_name="bids")
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment, blank=True, related_name="comments")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    restoredimage = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
```

View:

```
  # Create image save path with title
  img_save_path = "%s/%s%s" % (save_path, "image", img_extension)
  with open(img_save_path, "wb+") as f:
      for chunk in img.chunks():
          f.write(chunk)
  listing.restoredimage = None
  listing.restoredimage = cv2.imread(img_save_path)
```

Sorry I new to Django I don´t know if I'm doing right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you haven't initiated `listing` as a variable that represents an instance of the `Listing` class. To do so, you can do

```py
listing = Listing(my_model)
```

before the

```py
listing.restoredimage = None
listing.restoredimage = cv2.imread(img_save_path)
```

code